# Increasing Quantity via CSV Import Magento 2

Tags: import, quantity

We are working heavily and daily with the Magento 2 CSV import. We use something like this

```
"sku","qty"
"12345","100"
```

In this case, the qty for 12345 is set to be 100.

The next day I would like to upload something like this:

```
"sku","qty"
"12345","5"
```

The problem now is that 12345 will have 5 qty, and not 105 or ar at least 5 + (100 - sold qty).

Is there any way I can increase the quantity with the upload file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind using third-party tools, you can use the Store Manager software and i think there must be an expression formula to add qty the way you need at the step of import

Answer (score 0):

I was also stucked in same situation, after checking the core code got two solutions.

You have to make changes as according to your need.

**My Module Name is Conceptive_Commerce, You have to replace that name with your module name**

**Method 1 - using plugin**

**app\code\Conceptive\Commerce\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Import\Data">
        <plugin name="rewrite_source_import_method" type="Conceptive\Commerce\Plugin\ImportData" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"  />
    </type>
</config>
```

**app\code\Conceptive\Commerce\Plugin\ImportData.php**

```
<?php

namespace Conceptive\Commerce\Plugin;

class ImportData
{
    protected $request;
    protected $sourceinventorys;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\InventoryCatalogAdminUi\Model\GetSourceItemsDataBySku $sourceinventorys,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->sourceinventorys = $sourceinventorys;
    }

    public function aftergetNextBunch(\Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Import\Data $subject, $result)
    {
        if (is_array($result)) {
            $params = $this->request->getParams();
            if ($params['entity'] == "stock_sources" && $params['behavior'] == "append") {
                foreach ($result as $key => $data) {
                    $sourceCode = $data['source_code'];
                    $sku = $data['sku'];
                    $stockSources = $this->sourceinventorys->execute($sku);
                    foreach ($stockSources as $stockSource) {
                        if ($stockSource['source_code'] == $sourceCode) {
                            $qty = $stockSource['quantity'];
                            if ($qty) {
                                $result[$key]['quantity'] =  $data['quantity'] + $qty;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

**Method 2 using prefrence**

**app\code\Conceptive\Commerce\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Import\Data" type="Conceptive\Commerce\Rewrite\ImportData" />
</config>
```

**app\code\Conceptive\Commerce\Rewrite\ImportData.php**

```
<?php

namespace Conceptive\Commerce\Rewrite;

class ImportData extends \Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Import\Data
{
    /**
     * Get next bunch of validated rows.
     *
     * @return array|null
     */
    public function getNextBunch()
    {
        if (null === $this->_iterator) {
            $this->_iterator = $this->getIterator();
            $this->_iterator->rewind();
        }
        $dataRow = null;
        if ($this->_iterator->valid()) {
            $encodedData = $this->_iterator->current();
            if (array_key_exists(0, $encodedData) && $encodedData[0]) {
                $dataRow = $this->jsonHelper->jsonDecode($encodedData[0]);
                // custom code for increasing the quantity
                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $params = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http')->getParams();
                if ($params['entity'] == "stock_sources" && $params['behavior'] == "append") {
                    foreach ($dataRow as $key=>$data) {
                        $sourceCode = $data['source_code'];
                        $sku = $data['sku'];
                        $sourceinventorys = $objectManager->get('\Magento\InventoryCatalogAdminUi\Model\GetSourceItemsDataBySku');
                        $stockSources = $sourceinventorys->execute($sku);
                        foreach($stockSources as $stockSource) {
                            if ($stockSource['source_code'] == $sourceCode) {
                                $qty = $stockSource['quantity'];
                                if ($qty) {
                                    $dataRow[$key]['quantity'] =  $data['quantity'] + $qty;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                // custom code end

                $this->_iterator->next();
            }
        }
        if (!$dataRow) {
            $this->_iterator = null;
        }
        return $dataRow;
    }
}
```

**After adding files run the below commands**

1. bin/mgento setup:di:compile
2. bin/magento cache:clean
3. bin/magento cache:flush

**Note : If not worked than try it by running upgrade and deploy command as well**